# Error when calculating average on dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable

Suppose we have a dictionary:

```
mapping = {1: 22.5, 8: 13.4, 10: 12.1}
```

Then to compute average value I use the following:

```
[(sum(v) / len(v)) for k, v in mapping.items()]
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Any advice?

Comment: `sum(dict.values()) / len(dict)`. And try to avoid shadowing built-in functions/types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to calculate the sum of **one** value:

```
[(sum(v) / len(v)) for k, v in mapping.items()]
```

`v` is a single `float` object from the dictionary. It has no length, and can't be summed.

You want to sum **all** values, and take the length of the dictionary here:

```
sum(mapping.values()) / len(mapping)
```

Demo:

```
>>> mapping = {1: 22.5, 8: 13.4, 10: 12.1}
>>> sum(mapping.values()) / len(mapping)
16.0
```